# Google chrome is extremely slow to start (vs firefox, chromuim etc)

Tags: google-chrome

I've installed a fresh copy of ubuntu over windows on my XPS 17 9720

I intend to run google chrome as my main browser and everything has worked fine till I've tinkered with the auto-login/fingerprint settings.

Google chrome now takes significantly longer to bootup with the message along the lines of "Enter password for keyring to unlock".

I've disabled auto-login (requires password to login now) but chrome still remains slow to start.

Any advise is appreciated

EDIT: any other programs/apps that moves past where google chrome is supposed to boot will lead to this image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/lcSfS.jpg for approx 5 to 10 secs

Comment: Please, try running it with `HOME=/tmp` env. variable being set *(something like `HOME=/tmp google-chrome`, just substitute the binary name if it differs)*, and see if it still exhibits the problem. If it doesn't, then the quickest fix might be to re-create Chrome configuration. Not sure where exactly it's placed, but offhand I see this directory on my system `~/.config/google-chrome/`, it might be the one.

Answer (score 1):

Same setup, same issue. I should mention I'm using X and not Wayland. Your issue might be different based on what display server you use, as Chromium-based apps will run differently in either of those 2 environments.

What worked for me:

- navigate to `chrome://settings/system`
- make sure "Use hardware acceleration when available" is toggled off.

Alternative solution (although I'm not 100% sure what its consequences are and whether it doesn't just work by accident):

- run `google-chrome` or `google-chrome-stable` with `--use-gl=desktop`. This might work as well, but you might get some extra errors, and it would be ideal to debug them and figure out what the root cause is. If you want to do this for desktop shortcuts, modify `/usr/share/applications/google-chrome.desktop`, specifically the lines with `Exec`.

If all else fails, calling the `google-chrome` binary in the terminal will also give you a decent amount of debug info which will potentially lead you to a better/permanent solution than either of the two I've proposed.

Comment: "Use hardware acceleration when available" This. ALSO works for Opera if that one is slow.